# JavaScript callback - multithreading

Tags: javascript, jquery, multithreading, html, callback

I want to develope a very simple strategic game.
You can find an example on http://wiesenberg.info/hope/ !

If you click on a button, that project will be created (progressbar). After it is finished, the project will show up on the playground. As you can see it works if you click one by one. But once you click a button twice (start 2 project of the same kind), the second project will not be finished because the first has not finished and increased the variable. Is there an easy way of doing multithreading or just solving my bug?

I also want to add a function that you can stop the project by clicking on the progressbar. I tried it out, it dissapears in the list, but the icon still shows up, because the function didnt get that another function was executed. so I also need a break function for the progressbar. I hope you undertood my problem! Thanks

Heres the important code:

```
function addSygehus() {
    sygehusBarID++;
    sygehusID++;
    $("#addProject").append("<div id=sygehus" + sygehusID +
            " class='progress progress-striped active'><div class='progress-bar progress-bar-success' id=sygehusbar"
            + sygehusBarID + " aria-valuetransitiongoal='100'>Sygehus</div></div>");
    function countdown(callback) {
        var bar = document.getElementById("sygehusbar"+sygehusBarID),
                time = 0, max = firsttime,
                int = setInterval(function() {
            bar.style.width = Math.floor(100 * time++ / max) + '%';
            if (time - 1 == max) {
                clearInterval(int);
                // 600ms - width animation time
                callback && setTimeout(callback, 600);
            }
        }, 1000);                            
    }

    countdown(function() {
        $("#sygehus" + sygehusID).remove();
        $("#sygehusPic" + sygehusID).show(1000);

    });
}
```

Comment: Javascript only has one thread, the only other option would be webworkers or asynchronous behaviour (which would be hard to fake with synchronous actions).

Comment: so there is no workaround? Is there another way of doing the progressbar? A faster way than this countdown thing?

Comment: This is not a problem about multithreading or anything. Its just a matter of having the code that cancels the progressbar also do any necesasry cleanup (calling clearInterval, deleting any divs, etc). However, we cant helop you with that without the code that cancless the progress bar.

Answer (score 0):

I would look at JQuery Deferred (http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.Deferred/) and Promises Documentation in general to manage what your trying to achieve. So you can apply some control to the order in which the asynchronous calls occur.

You've also got Q.js (https://github.com/kriskowal/q) is a nice library for managing these kinds of scenarios.

Otherwise you have web workers as already mentioned for emulating multithreaded behaviour but I don't think that's what your looking for.